# Insert special sign between characters

Tags: java, string

I have a String which has numbers and I want to add this sign ":" between every two numbers as if the string was **0123456789** I want it to be like this **01:23:45:67:89**

Is there any way to insert it  ?? as I read about replace() but this does not help in my case

Comment: yep. by writing some code...What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: show some of your effort ... :) as if you had tried something

Comment: I read about replace but I dont think it helps here

Comment: lookup up stringbuilder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this magic piece of regex:

```
System.out.println("0123456789".replaceAll(".{2}(?!$)", "$0:"));
```

- `.{2}` match 2 characters
- `(?!$)` not at end
- `$0:` First matched argument with `:` included

Answer (score 0):

```
String x="0123456789";
String result="";
for(int i=0;i<x.length();i++){
    result+=x.charAt(i);
    if(i%2==1 && i+1<x.length())
       result+=":";
}
```